# How to get value of node at xpath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the value of the LogicalId tag.  Here is my xml which is compiled into a Document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProcessCreditApplication xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalId>www.refijet.com/ysg/defi_routeone</LogicalId>
...
```

The java code that processes it is below:

```
        String expression = "//*[not(*)]";
        NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.compile(expression).evaluate(structure_xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            names.add(nl.item(i).getNodeName());
            Node node = nl.item(i);
            String path = "";
            while (node != null) {
                path = node.getNodeName() + '/' + path;
                node = node.getParentNode();
            }

            //now get the value of the node located at path in the passed xml
            path = path.replace("#document/", "");  //get rid of the #document/ at the start of the path
            path = path.substring(0,path.length()-1);   //get rid of the / at the end to prevent illegal path
            System.out.println(path);
            expr = xpath.compile(path);
            Object result = expr.evaluate(xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
            node = nodes.item(0);
            System.out.println("node value="+node.getNodeValue());
        }
```

Here is the value of path:

> ProcessCreditApplication/ApplicationArea/Sender/LogicalId

I have also tried putting a "/" and a "//" in front, but result is the same.
Here is the value of result:

> node value=null

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you only wanted to get the text inside the LogicalId tag then the XPath should get the text node in it with the XPath expression 
 ProcessCreditApplication/ApplicationArea/Sender/LogicalId/text() . Or are you trying to achieve something else?

Comment: Ahh!  I didn't know about text().  That worked, thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. Cheers!